# Hello, I'm needing a little assistance with this python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, compiler-errors, linked-list

I have completed the code for my class down to part 3 where I need assistance. I am removing the duplicates but it only removes half of the duplicates. If there is anything else I need to add please let me know. I have also attached the guidance document as well as the expected outcome I was given.

Here is the code I'm working with.

```
""" File: useBag.py Author: Derrf Seitz

This program exercises bags.

The following files must be in the same folder:
  abstractcollection.py
  abstractbag.py
  arraybag.py
  arrays.py
  ball.py
  linkedbag.py
  node.py
"""

# <your name>

# Replace <your name> with your name.
# Replace any "<your code>" comments with your own code statement(s)
# to accomplish the specified task.
# DO NOT CHANGE ANY OTHER CODE.

# IMPORTANT NOTE:
# We can use a simple "for" loop to traverse a collection.
# We will call this "regular iteration" or, for brevity, simply "iteration".
# During a regular iteration, you cannot add or remove an item from a framework collection!
# Breaking this rule will cause an immediate exception to occur.
# The exception will display a message and terminate (crash) your program!
# The displayed message is: "Illegal modification of backing store".
# Note that you can update item attributes during iteration.
# Later in this course, we will learn about special "list iterators".
# Unlike regular iterators, list iterators allow modification (add and remove) during iteration.

from arraybag import ArrayBag
from ball import Ball
from linkedbag import LinkedBag
from node import Node

# Part 1:
# This function takes a bag that has red and blue balls in it
# and moves the balls to two other bags: one to hold the red
# balls and one to hold the blue balls. Every red ball is inflated
# to twice its radius before being added to its new bag.
#
# Preconditions:
#   bag - an ArrayBag containing zero or more red and blue Ball objects. 
#
# Postconditions:
#   returns - a bag containing the doubled radius red balls and
#             a bag containing the blue balls.
#   The original bag should be emptied.
def distributeBag(bag):
    redBag = ArrayBag()
    blueBag = ArrayBag()

    # Move the balls to the appropriate bags:

    # Return the 2 bags:
    return (redBag, blueBag)

# Part 2:
# This function prints the items in a bag, each on a separate line.
def printBag(bag):
    for item in bag:
        str(item)
        print(item)
        
    if bag.isEmpty():
        print('empty')
    print()
# Part 3:
# This function removes duplicate items from a bag.
# Postconditions:
#   Any item that appears more than once will be reduced to a single occurrence.
#   Example: If there were 3 of item A, there will only be 1 of item A remaining.
def removeDuplicates(bag):
    for i in bag:
        if bag.count(i) >=2:
            bag.remove(i)
            return i
# Test 1:
    print("Test 1:")
bag1 = ArrayBag([Ball("red", 10),
                Ball("red", 11),
                Ball("red", 12),
                Ball("blue", 15),
                Ball("blue", 15),
                Ball("blue", 15)])
print("Original mixed bag:")
printBag(bag1)
redBag, blueBag = distributeBag(bag1)
print("Red bag:")
printBag(redBag)
print("Blue bag:")
printBag(blueBag)
print("Final mixed bag:")
printBag(bag1)

# Test 2:
print("Test 2:")
bag2 = ArrayBag([Ball("red", 201),
                Ball("red", 201),
                Ball("red", 202),
                Ball("red", 202)])
print("Original mixed bag:")
printBag(bag2)
redBag, blueBag = distributeBag(bag2)
print("Red bag:")
printBag(redBag)
print("Blue bag:")
printBag(blueBag)
print("Final mixed bag:")
printBag(bag2)

# Test 3:
print("Test 3:")
bag3 = ArrayBag()
print("Original mixed bag:")
printBag(bag3)
redBag, blueBag = distributeBag(bag3)
print("Red bag:")
printBag(redBag)
print("Blue bag:")
printBag(blueBag)
print("Final mixed bag:")
printBag(bag3)

# Test 4:
print("Test 4:")
bag4 = LinkedBag(["apple",
                  "apple",
                  "banana",
                  "kiwi",
                  "cantaloupe",
                  "pear",
                  "banana",
                  "orange",
                  "orange",
                  "cantaloupe",
                  "apple",
                  "lemon",
                  "lime",
                  "lime"])
print("Original bag with duplicates:")
printBag(bag4)
removeDuplicates(bag4)
print("Bag after removing duplicates:")
printBag(bag4)
```

Expected Outcome

```
Test 1: Original mixed bag: red ball, radius 10 red ball, radius 11 red ball, radius 12 blue ball, radius 15 blue ball, radius 15 blue ball, radius 15

Red bag:
red ball, radius 20
red ball, radius 22
red ball, radius 24

Blue bag:
blue ball, radius 15
blue ball, radius 15
blue ball, radius 15

Final mixed bag:
empty

Test 2:
Original mixed bag:
red ball, radius 201
red ball, radius 201
red ball, radius 202
red ball, radius 202

Red bag:
red ball, radius 402
red ball, radius 402
red ball, radius 404
red ball, radius 404

Blue bag:
empty

Final mixed bag:
empty

Test 3:
Original mixed bag:
empty

Red bag:
empty

Blue bag:
empty

Final mixed bag:
empty

Test 4:
Original bag with duplicates:
lime
lime
lemon
apple
cantaloupe
orange
orange
banana
pear
cantaloupe
kiwi
banana
apple
apple

Bag after removing duplicates:
lime
lemon
orange
pear
cantaloupe
kiwi
banana
apple
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! This is far too much information, we ask that questions consist of a [mcve] with sample input, only enough code to reproduce the problem, and expected output, along with a description of how it's different than your current output. Please [edit] your question down to only the relevant details as it makes it easier for people to know how to help

Comment: That said, don't change an object while you're iterating over it. When you do "for i in foo: if bar: foo.remove(i)`, that changes the indices of your iteration and makes it behave in ways you don't want

Comment: @G.Anderson Thanks for the feedback on how to post things on Stack Overflow. This is my first post and certainly won't be my last now I know how to post things on here.